# How to read Specific row from data set

Tags: c#

This is the code where I have created a table. This code returns the all rows but I want only specific row where Price of item is greater than 6.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable MyTable = GetTable(); // Get the data table.

        foreach (DataRow row in MyTable.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- Row ---");
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
            {
                Console.Write("Item: "); 
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        Console.Read(); // Pause.
    }

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(15, "Bag");
        table.Rows.Add(4, "Candies");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Cookies");
        table.Rows.Add(20, "Books");
        table.Rows.Add(8, "Chocolates");
        return table;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the Price before showing it, like this:

```js
foreach (DataRow row in MyTable.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- Row ---");
            if (row["Price"] > 6)
            {
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
                {
                    Console.Write("Item: "); 
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I added a missing end parentes!

Comment: What happens when you try? Does it throw an exception or what?

Comment: it simply generates the all output does not show the specific rows

Comment: Have you inserted the 'if (row["Price"] > 6)' as shown?